# how can i delete the channel room when i went out the channel discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        await member.guild.system_channel.send(
            "{} into the voice room".format(member.nick)
        )
        channel = await member.guild.create_text_channel('123')

    if before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        await member.guild.system_channel.send(
            "{} out of the voice room".format(member.nick)
        )
        channel = await member.guild.delete_text_channel('123')
```

when I go into the voice channel, bot make a text channel
and if I left the voice channel, bot should delete the
text channel

but when I go out, bot does not delete the channel
How do I fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

.delete_text_channel() is invalid, you must use .delete() instead

```
channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="123")
# If channel doesn't exits or channel is not TextChannel
if type(channel) != discord.channel.TextChannel or channel is None: 
    print("No channel found!")
    return
await channel.delete()
```